# Event handling in Moodle 2.8

Tags: events, handler, moodle

The objective is to copy two custom profile fields into the user table upon user create or update using the event triggers by the same name.  But for some reason, the events are not triggering.  I created a new module for /local/newuser with the required three files, as shown below.

Any and all hints would be appreciated.

Code from events.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$handlers = array (
    'user_updated' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/local/newuser/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_newuser_user_updated',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
    ),

    'user_created' => array (
        'handlerfile'      => '/local/newuser/lib.php',
        'handlerfunction'  => 'local_newuser_user_created',
        'schedule'         => 'instant',
    ),
);
```

code from lib.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

function local_newuser_user_updated($user) {
    require('../../config.php');
    global $DB;
    $userid = $user->id;
    $data1 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=1', null);
    $data2 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=2', null);
    if ($data1 !='' ) {
        $sql="UPDATE {user} set idnumber='$data1',department='$data2' where id=$userid";
        $DB->execute($sql);
    }
    return true;
}

function local_newuser_user_created($user) {
    require('../../config.php');
    global $DB;
    $userid = $user->id;
    $data1 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=1', null);
    $data2 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=2', null);
    if ($data1 !='' ) {
        $sql="UPDATE {user} set idnumber='$data1',department='$data2' where id=$userid";
        $DB->execute($sql);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And of course, version.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version   = 2014030200; // Plugin version.
$plugin->requires  = 2013051402; // Moodle version.
$plugin->component = 'local_newuser'; // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics).
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your lib.php's require(), it should be require_once(dirname(dirname(**DIR**)) . '/config.php'); and put it on the top of the page

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
require_once(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/config.php');

function local_newuser_user_updated($user) {
    global $DB;
    $userid = $user->id;
    $data1 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=1', null);
    $data2 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=2', null);
    if ($data1 !='' ) {
        $sql="UPDATE {user} set idnumber='$data1',department='$data2' where id=$userid";
        $DB->execute($sql);
    }
    return true;
}

function local_newuser_user_created($user) {
    global $DB;
    $userid = $user->id;
    $data1 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=1', null);
    $data2 = $DB->get_field_select('user_info_data', 'data', 'userid='.$userid.' AND fieldid=2', null);
    if ($data1 !='' ) {
        $sql="UPDATE {user} set idnumber='$data1',department='$data2' where id=$userid";
        $DB->execute($sql);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The events have completely changed in Moodle 2.7 onwards. They use classes now so the event 'user_updated' doesn't exist. You will need to rewrite your code unfortunately.

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Event_2#Event_dispatching_and_observers

for example

```
$observers = array(
    array(
        'eventname'   => '\core\event\user_updated',
        'callback'    => 'yourclass::yourfunction',
    )
);
```

Also you don't need to include config.php in lib or class files. You only need to include config.php in pages that are viewable by the user.

Comment: I have made the changes, but still nothing. 
`code` 
    $observers = array(

    array(
      'eventname' => 'core\event\user_created',
      'callback'  => 'local_newuser_user_observer::user_created',
      'includefile' => '/local/newuser/lib.php'
      'internal'  => false, // Get events only after transaction commit.
      'priority'  => 1000,
    )

Comment: did you bump the version number in version.php? This will update the events

Comment: Yes.  The lib.php is being called because if I put a bad path to config.php, it complains, but I cannot get either function to trigger.  So I'm missing smething.

Comment: Based on my lib.php above, what should the callback line look like:

'callback' => 'local_newuser::local_newuser_user_created';

Comment: yeah you'll need to create an obsever class in the classes folder for this - I'll try to provide an example but short on time at the minute, search the moodle code for user_updated for an example  - also lib.php is called by Moodle anyway not just for events, it  will look for specific functions such as cron. Ideally local functions should be stored in locallib.php rather than lib.php